# Urdu font rendering issue in android 4.1

Tags: android, fonts, rendering, android-4.2-jelly-bean

One of my letters does not render properly in android 4.1 :

[image]

The same renders fine on 4.2 and 4.3 :

[image]

I would like to fix this if possible, any ideas how?

Comment: Are you using a custom font, what android ROM are you using ?. try to use a custom font that support Urdu.

Comment: I am using the standard android, on real devices and emulator. I believe the font used is Droid Arabic Naskh but I cannot be sure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad rendering of "heh" in that example is due to a mistake in the Droid Arabic Naskh font. It was fixed by an update in October 2012. (See report here — https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd31db60ee6df6dd84bce9925e96b6cccbdf522d)

The relevant changes is:

> Fixed shaping of U+06C1 HEH GOAL.

This explains why it displays correctly in the newer versions of Android.

The updated fonts are available on Github at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/data/fonts. Click "DroidNaskh-Regular.ttf", then "view raw" to download the font.

(It seems the counterpart font "Droid Kufi" still has this bug.)

Comment: Many thanks, my idea is to add that one character to my custom font any apply it, it will override the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by the user3152053 was helpful. The Droid Arabic Naskh had some coding problem as he told.

But unfortunately link provided by him didn't contain the suggested file. Here is the new Github link which contains the corrected file "DroidNaskh_Arabic.ttf".

My "ہ U+06C1 HEH GOAL" problem was solved by downloading the file from the link below:

https://github.com/vokal/android_frameworks_base/tree/master/data/fonts