# Sinhala font different in ICS compared to Jelly Bean

Tags: java, android, fonts

I'm using a font called iskpota.ttf to enable Sinhala text input in the Android application I'm developing. I would love to make it available for ICS and upwards. But ICS does not render the font correctly so I'm forced to make the app available only for Jelly Bean and upwards.

I'm setting the font to the text field by using the following code.

```
EditText editT = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "iskpota.ttf");
editT.setTypeface(font);
```

Font rendered in ICS 4.0 (wrong)

[image: Font rendered in ICS]

Font rendered in Jelly Bean 4.2.2 (correct)

[image]

Note: Above are emulator screenshots.

Anybody knows a fix for ICS?

Comment: what are the jellybeans and ICS versions?can you update the question with versions? I found similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826690/urdu-font-rendering-issue-in-android-4-1

Comment: @lakshman I added the ICS and Jelly Bean versions